# DynamoDB - In a table with a composite key (hash and range), how can I PUT an item only when the hash key doesn't already exist in the table?

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk

We have a `partition_key` and a `sort_key` column that together comprise the key for the table.

We're using the AWS SDK in C#.  Is there a way to set the `ConditionExpression` in our `PutItemRequest` to only insert the row if the `partition_key` is unique?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32833351/dynamodb-put-item-if-hash-or-hash-and-range-combination-doesnt-exist