# DynamoDB PutItem require GSI partition key to already exist

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I would like PutItem to succeed only if the GSI partition key for the new item already exists on another item.

Suppose my table has these items (omitting some attributes):

```
PK       GSI1PK    GSI1SK
1        a         b
2        c         d
```

And I am attempting to put this item:

```
{
  PK: 3,
  GSI1PK: "e",
  GSI1SK: "f"
}
```

I want this PutItem request to fail, since the table does not yet contain an item with GSI1PK == "e".

I'd like to solve this with a condition expression if possible. I would not like to solve this by querying the table before the PutItem request.

Here is how I have attempted this with an example (go sdk) that I would like to *succeed*:

```
input := &dynamodb.PutItemInput{
    Item: map[string]*dynamodb.AttributeValue{
        "PK":         intAttrVal(3),
        "GSI1PK":     stringAttrVal("a"),
        "GSI1SK":     stringAttrVal("f"),
    },
    ConditionExpression: stringRef("attribute_exists(GSI1PK)"),
    TableName:           &tableName,
}
```

But and exception is thrown: "ConditionalCheckFailedException: The conditional request failed".

Comment: In your example of put request you want to fail, you mention "...the table does not yet contain an item with GSI1PK == "d", yet the item has "GSI1PK: "e"". Is this correct?

Comment: @PerttuHaliseva That was a typo. I fixed it.

Comment: From what I see, this might not be possible. Here's a related answer which explains the issue better than I can: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32833351/dynamodb-put-item-if-hash-or-hash-and-range-combination-doesnt-exist

Answer (score 1):

I do not really see a way to do this since the value you want to check is on another item. Therefore, put the two operations a ConditionCheck and PutItem in a [DynamoDB transaction](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/transactions.html). If the conditional check, which checks if the value in the other item exists, and the PutItem succeed, then you're good. If the conditional check fails, so does the PutItem.

Comment: For now I am doing that, but without the transaction. Thanks. Will accept your answer if no one offers a way to do it in on PutItem request.

Comment: At least with the transaction, you are not doing round trips to the DB. it is all in one trip.

Comment: Doing a `GetItem` and `PutItem` operations in the same transaction is not supported. However, I believe this is the right direction. You could to a `ConditionCheck` followed by a `Put`. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/transaction-example.html

Comment: Good catch. Not sure why I was stuck on getitem. You are correct, it is ConditionCheck, not a GetItem. I changed my answer to say this correctly.

Comment: Can I do a `ConditionCheck` with GSI? I think it requires the primary key.